# how to display CR2 (Camera Raw) file in html img tag

Tags: html, vuejs3

I have created a web application using Laravel 9 and Vue 3 that can upload files.
I was trying to preview a CR2 file-type image, but it won't display on the browser.

how am I able to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, what is a "CR2 file-type" and also, what did you tried so far? Some code/effort is welcome.

Comment: it's a  RAW digital photography file format, it is an image type of file like jpeg.

what I have tried is using only <img src="/path/to/imageFile.vr2" />, but nothing is displayed

Comment: Try that into a generic `.html` file initially IMO. Also, I can't find anything about that format. Do you have a link? Not all format are supported out of the box in a browser.

Comment: CR2 is RAW and not supported by browsers direct. You should convert it to jpeg/png. Or otherwise you have to write a RAW development plugin for browser.

Comment: Raw is also quite huge + more of a multi-layered video more than an actual image. Not meant to be shared on a web platform anyway.